# fsockopen cannot reach one host

Tags: php, fsockopen

I used 'classic' code with `fsockopen()` to 'ping' necessary hosts. I had no problem with it at all.
But I can't reach one host, always receiving `error 110 : Connection timed out`.

But other instruments, like paping, or http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ confirm that the host is online.

```
$domain = 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX';

$port = '40001';                                                            

$starttime = microtime(true);
$file      = fsockopen($domain, $port, $errno, $errstr, 20);
$stoptime  = microtime(true);

$status    = 0;

if ($file === false) {
    echo $errno." : ".$errstr."</br>";
}

if (!$file) {
    $status = -1;  // Site is down
    echo 'camera ping failed'.'</br>';
}
else {
    fclose($file);
    $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
    $status = floor($status);
}
```

Thanks for any advice or ideas.

Comment: You should give more details about your question. Which host you're trying to reach? What error do you get when you call `fsockopen()`? Please give us some output.

Comment: error 110 : Connection timed out. It's IP camera, so, no domain names. Thanks at advance

Comment: *Connection timed out* means that the host you're trying to reach could not be reached. The problem here seems to be a network issue, not a programming error.

Comment: First of all try to `telnet XXX.XX.XXX.XXX 40001` from a terminal and check  connection: so you can check where is a problem (telnet — network problems). For example, there is a IP block rules on a `$domain` server for your client.